# Windows Service Won't Stop (C#)

Tags: c#, python, windows, windows-services

I have made a Windows Service in C# that calls a python script to run. This works without a problem. However, when I go to stop the service, it gives the error "could not be stopped" and I have to manually kill it using the PID in the command line. This hasn't always been like this and I can't seem to find previous versions of my code in VS2017. What part of my code is causing the Windows service to not be able to close?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.Permissions;

namespace WindowsService1
{
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
    {
    public ThreadStart startScript;
    public Thread PyScriptThread;
    public ServerClass serverObject;
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public Service1() { InitializeComponent(); }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        serverObject = new ServerClass();

        PyScriptThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(serverObject.PyScript));
        var t = Task.Run(() => serverObject.PyScriptAsync(PyScriptThread));
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\bakere1\A19149\Projects\text_doc.txt", false);
            sw.Write("***STOP***");
            sw.Close();                                //stop the script within the process


            if (!serverObject.p.HasExited)             //kill the process within the thread
            {
                serverObject.p.CancelErrorRead();
                serverObject.p.CancelOutputRead();
                serverObject.p.CloseMainWindow();
                serverObject.p.Refresh();
                serverObject.p.Close();
                serverObject.p.Kill();
                serverObject.p.Dispose();
            }

            serverObject.PyScriptAsync(PyScriptThread).Dispose();

            killPyThread(PyScriptThread);             //kill the overarching thread

            base.OnStop();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex is IOException || ex is ThreadInterruptedException || ex is ThreadAbortException || ex is InvalidOperationException)
            {
                StreamWriter errorSW = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\bakere1\A19149\Projects\text_doc.txt", true);
                errorSW.Write("Error occurred: Stacktrace/Message/Source", ex.StackTrace, ex.Message, ex.Source);
                errorSW.Close();
            }
        }
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [SecurityPermissionAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, ControlThread = true)]
    public void killPyThread(Thread thread)
    {
        thread.Interrupt();
        thread.Abort();
    }

}

public class ServerClass
{
    public event System.EventHandler serviceChanged;
    public Process p;
    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public async Task PyScriptAsync(Thread thread)
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000).ConfigureAwait(false);
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void PyScript()
    {
        string fileName = @"C:\Users\bakere1\A19149\Projects\BLE_Advertiser.py";
        p = new Process
        {
            StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Python36_64\python.exe", fileName)
            {
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                CreateNoWindow = false
            }
        };
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForExit();

        p.CancelErrorRead();
        p.CancelOutputRead();
        p.CloseMainWindow();
        p.Refresh();
        p.Close();
        p.Kill();
        p.Dispose();

        return;
    }

    //-------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected virtual void onServiceChanged()
    {
        serviceChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think you should make t (your Task) global and stop it in OnStop function

Comment: I made it global just now, added " t.Dispose();" after the "killPyThread" in 'onStop', although, I was still receiving the error. I found out by using the Windows Event Manager that a thread was accessing the text file at the same time I was trying to overwrite it with the "***STOP***" signal I had set up. Once I made sure to close the program accessing the text file it worked.

Comment: Good job, glad to hear that.