# Windows service hanging on exit

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-services

I have a Windows service that I wrote. In a certain, rare instances I need to have the service restart itself. If I call "System.Environment.Exit(1)" it will cause the service to exit and then Windows will start it back up, which is exactly what I need to do. The problem is sometimes, not always, the service hangs when I do this this. And at that point even going into services and trying to stop the service doesn't work. The only way is to force quit it through task manager. I've made sure I'm exiting all threads and cleaning everything up. And all threads are started with "IsBackground=true" anyway, so those shouldn't be an issue.

I can't see anything else that could be preventing it from exiting. Does anyone have any idea what else could be the problem? Or is there a better way I can have my service restart itself without having this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Debug it with OnStop() method in your ServiceBase derived class, and see if OnStop is being hit at all. If not, something is blocking the shutdown. If OnStart() never finishes, that could be the reason.

Comment: OnStart does finish. OnStop never gets called at all. Wouldn't that only get called if the service was properly stopped and not quit through .Exit?

Comment: I think you need to implement some kind of cancellation token for your main process. The process started in OnStart seems to hold the exit - at least that is what I suspect.

Comment: Have you checked this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52936562/windows-service-wont-stop-c

Comment: I'm using cancelationtokens on all the threads and I can see they are all exiting before I'm trying to kill the service.